# List.remove(x): x not in list, using an iteration

Tags: python

```
defecttodelete = [defect for defect in variables.defectlist 
                         if defect.defectorderno == defecttodeleteorderno]

if defecttodelete is not None:
    variables.defectlist .remove(defecttodelete)
```

With the above code, I want to find an object in a list and delete it. Yet I get a x not in list error. Normally I get the object from the iteration in that list.

Comment: `defecttodelete` will never be `None`. It's a `list`.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to get a set of things to remove from another set of things. May I suggest a set.difference operation?

Comment: Actually, i was trying to get a sinlge object yet I was getting the whole list :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest simply reassigning your list variable to a new list, note the only difference in the list comprehension is the inversion of the logic for inclusion in the list:

```
variables.defectlist = [defect for defect in variables.defectlist 
                                   if defect.defectorderno != defecttodeleteorderno]
```

You could also use sets here, if both sets are useful, order doesn't matter, and elements are hashable. But since you're using lists, I'm not going to implement.

But repetitive use of `list.remove` isn't very performant. You comment:

> I am trying to get a single object from list; based on a filter. What's the best way to achieve that? Lambdas?

I would use a simple for loop and break when I get the right element:

```
for defect in variables.defectlist:
    if defect.defectorderno != defecttodeleteorderno:
        break
else: # runs if no break happens.
    defect = None
    print('no break, defect not found')
print(defect)
```

Careful if using `next` similarly, if there's nothing to return, and you have no default, it will raise StopIteration.

```
>>> next(i for i in [])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

So provide it with a default sentinel:

```
>>> next((i for i in []), None)
```

Comment: I am trying to get a sinlge object from list;based on a filter.Whats the best way to achieve that?Lambdas?

Comment: @Sin5k4, did I answer your question?

Comment: Aye,i went ahead and get the item using next() function :)

Comment: Careful, that raises StopIteration if the element isn't found, but otherwise it's just as clean as my second suggestion.

Comment: @Sin5k4 I added a note addressing your usage, and how to avoid raising StopIteration.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to remove the entire list, which isn't in your defectlist.  Instead you need to do:

```
for item in defecttodelete:
     variables.defectlist.remove(item)
```

If you know that your list of items to delete will only contain zero or one elements, you could do:

```
if defecttodelete:
    variables.defectlist.remove(defecttodelete[0])
```

Comment: slow, sets are much faster.

Comment: @AaronHall: Whether a set can be used depends on other factors not discussed in the question.  For instance, you can't use a set if you want to retain duplicates in the original list.

Comment: Also, a one-liner: `[item in variables.defectlist if item not in defecttodelete]`. Returns a new list, because mutating data usually sucks.

Comment: @9000 Shouldn't it be `[item for item in variables.defectlist if item not in defecttodelete]`?

Comment: Agree, don't know enough to provide sets as an answer, but `.remove` strikes me as particularly slow.

Comment: @matsjoyce: yes, it should.